# Скажите, пожалуйста, где поставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис

Он не захотел с нами гулять(1) потому(2) что был голодным.

Мой друг(1) несмотря на боль(2) продолжал идти дальше.

Сильно взволнованная из-за дневных событий(?) девушка не могла уснуть.

Я так хочу, чтобы на улице растаял снег(?) и выглянуло солнышко.

Comment: Задания не рассматриваются без указания проблемы. В чём трудности?